# Transfer Learning on generative adversarial networks (GANs)

Tags: gan, transfer-learning

Is it possible to apply transfer learning to [GANs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network) and if so, what are some examples of someone having tried this?

Comment: Take a look at following examples https://biblio.ugent.be/publication/8521037/file/8521039.pdf http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2017/pdfs/313.pdf https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8301400/

Comment: Transfer learning on GANs is still an open field of research. You can find some works here: - https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Transferring-GANs%3A-Generating-Images-from-Limited-Wang-Wu/fac36fa1b809b71756c259f2c5db20add0cb0da0
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.11613 - https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/SDIT%3A-Scalable-and-Diverse-Cross-domain-Image-Wang-Gonzalez-Garcia/28dea7c409c031605e54e365c753af29c20bafec